# Upgrading Apache Beam version to 2.11.0 fails with orchestration through apache airflow

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-dataflow, airflow, apache-beam

Apache Beam Python SDK upgrade to 2.11.0 issue .

I am upgrading the sdk from 2.4.0 to 2.11.0  using requirements.txt. It has dependencies as below:

```
    apache_beam==2.11.0
    google-cloud-dataflow==2.4.0
    httplib2==0.11.3
    google-cloud==0.27.0
    google-cloud-storage==1.3.0
    workflow
```

For managing the dependencies in beam pipeline we have this txt file. There are two vm instance on google compute engine , one is master other is worker. These instances will install all packages listed in the requirements.txt file.

The jobs are run through DataflowRunner. If running the code manually using command as

python code.py --project  --setupFilePath  --requirementFilePath  --workerMachineType n1-standard-8  --runner DataflowRunner.

The job is not upgrading the version to 2.11.0 , rather it fails .Error Message in stackdriver logs:

```
2019-03-26 19:02:02.000 IST
Failed to install packages: failed to install requirements: exit status 1
Expand all | Collapse all {
 insertId:  "27857323862365974846:1225647:0:438995"  
 jsonPayload: {
  line:  "boot.go:144"   
  message:  "Failed to install packages: failed to install requirements: exit status 1"   
 }
 labels: {
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_id:  "278567544395974846"   
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_name:  "icf-20190334132038-03260625-b9fa-harness-gtml"   
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_type:  "instance"   
  dataflow.googleapis.com/job_id:  "2019-03-26_06_25_16-6068768320191854196"   
  dataflow.googleapis.com/job_name:  "icf-20190326132038"   
  dataflow.googleapis.com/region:  "global"   
 }
 logName:  "projects/project-id/logs/dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fworker-startup"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2019-03-26T13:32:07.627920858Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   job_id:  "2019-03-26_06_25_16-6068768320191854196"    
   job_name:  "icf-20190326132038"    
   project_id:  "project-id"    
   region:  "global"    
   step_id:  ""    
  }
  type:  "dataflow_step"   
 }
 severity:  "CRITICAL"  
 timestamp:  "2019-03-26T13:32:02Z"  
}
```

Note : When running the pip install apache-beam==2.11.0 on both worker and master , the code runs.*

Comment: The issue appearing with beam2.11.0 , 2.10,2.9 version. I downgraded the version to 2.8.0 and it worked using airflow 1.8.1

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but most likely the issue here without seeing the rest of the logs. Is an incompatible dependency. Are you able to run the pipeline locally and see if you have any dep issues?

Comment: Yes Alex , I was able to run the pipeline locally without any incompatible dependency mismatch.

Comment: Great, are there any other output logs folders in the stackdriver page on the GCP website? That would indicate the specific failure of the python setup?

I suspect the versions change when you run on GCP and somehow you have a version mismatch with the deps. I think you may be able to remove     google-cloud-dataflow==2.4.0 dep. Since the beam dep should be all you need with the later versions.